# How can you check if a value is in an addition table using hashing?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Lets use the following table below. How can I efficiently check if the value 11 is in the table? Note that the numbers in the yellow may not always be consecutive. Looping through all the values is n^2 but that's not very efficient.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is the following - put all the numbers either from the yellow row or the yellow column in some set, say hash set. Let's use the row for an example. After that iterate over the column and for each number `x` check if the number `A - x` is in the hash set(in your case A is 11). This approach would lead to linear complexity and linear additional memory. You do not need the hash set if you know that the numbers are sorted to get the same computational complexity.

Comment: What if the yellow row and column were not identical, but the same length. Say [1,4,6,8] and [2,3,4,5]

Comment: @user5516358 my algorithm does not rely on that at all. Once you see an entry in the column, you know what should be the entry in the row so that they sum up A

Comment: You switched from talking about a hash set to a hash table. Did you mean hash set?

Comment: A hash table is the typical way to implement a hash set. I will edit my answer for consistency.